# Is the solution to the Fredholm integral equation of the first kind a continuous analogue of Cramer's rule for matrix equations?

Tags: matrix-equations, intuition, integral-equations

When we have a system of of $n$ linear equations represented by $$A \overrightarrow{x} = \overrightarrow{b} $$ with $\overrightarrow{x} = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n})^{\intercal} $, we can solve for each component of this vector by means of Cramer's Rule: $$x_{i} = \frac{\det(A_{i})}{\det(A)}. \qquad \qquad (1)  $$ Here, $A_{i}$ is formed by replacing the $i$'th column of the column vector of $A$ by the vector $\overrightarrow{b}$.

I'm curious whether a similar rule exists for “[continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024034/matrices-with-continuous-indices)” matrix equations. When we consider the Fredholm [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation#Equation_of_the_first_kind) of the first kind:

$$g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(t,s) f(s) ds ,$$ the solution is given by $$f(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathcal{F}_{t} [g(t)](\omega) }{\mathcal{F}_{t} [K(t)](\omega) } e^{2\pi i \omega s} d \omega. \qquad \qquad (2)$$ Here, $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ is the Fourier transform.

My **questions** are:

1. Can $(2)$ be considered to be a continuous analogue of $(1)$, when one sets $s = s^{*}$ (a particular value of $s$) ?
2. If not, what *is* a continuous analogue of Cramer's rule for continuous matrix equations (involving integration against a kernel) ?

Comment: Here's the Wiki page on integral transforms and kernels: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform

Comment: cross posted https://mathoverflow.net/q/390291/11260